# Sorting data order by duration between start_date and end_date

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm using Laravel 7. I have a table named assistances witch has some columns and those two columns:

```
- start_date
- end_date
```

I'd like to sort data order by the **duration** between start_date and end_date:

```
 $query = Assistance::join('users', 'assistances.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('assistances.*')
        ->orderBy('duration between start_date and end_date');
 ;
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following - bare in mind that this is not hugely efficient

`DATEDIFF` returns the days between two dates. You may also want to use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` which accepts a first parameter such as 'hour' where you can get more granular control

```
$query = Assistance::join('users', 'assistances.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('assistances.*')
        ->orderBy(DB::raw('DATEDIFF(start_date, end_date)'))
        ->get();
```

Please also `use DB;` in your class.

Comment: to chose if is ASC or DESC I used orderByRaw  `->orderByRaw(DB::raw("DATEDIFF(start_date, end_date) desc"))`