# Find top 3 elements from the array with the longest time duration - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, datetime, filtering

I have an array with more than 2000 elements like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => LILI
            [actual_start] => 2021-11-10T18:34:00+00:00
            [actual_end] => 2021-11-10T21:32:00+00:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => MILI
            [actual_start] => 2021-11-18T17:33:00+00:00
            [actual_end] => 2022-03-18T19:36:00+00:00
    

    )
.
.
.
    )
```

My goal is to find the TOP 3 elements (their names) based on the duration from actual_start and actual_end.

First, I wanted to convert the difference of actual_start and actual_end to some number and then use that get the top 3 longest. I tried this:

```
foreach ($array as $data) {
    $date1 = new DateTime($data['actual_start']);
    $date2 = new DateTime($data['actual_end']);
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
    echo "difference " . $interval->y ;
}
```

This works but it will give me the difference in years or minutes or hours (if I change y to h or m), but using this value I cannot calculate top 3, any ideas?

Comment: Interval values can be directly compared with the usual operators (<, >, >=, etc.). See [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), in particular the example with the spaceship operator (<=>).

Comment: @sik is this data the result of a database query? If so, what database flavor are you using?

Comment: For Laravel: [Sorting data order by duration between start_date and end_date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64425638/2943403)

Comment: no this is not connected with the db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, just keep 3 numbers, each for max, 2nd max and 3rd max, thereby constituting your *top 3*.

Take the difference of `actual_end` and `actual_start` for each array using `strtotime`(although there are many ways to get a diff).

Keep comparing with those max variables and keep assigning and re-assigning them values. This would make it efficient in terms of time to retrieve the answer in just a single pass.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$max = $secondMax = $thirdMax = 0;
$maxName = $secondMaxName = $thirdMaxName = "";

foreach($data as $d){
    $diff = strtotime($d['actual_end']) - strtotime($d['actual_start']);
    if($diff > $max){
        $thirdMax = $secondMax;
        $secondMax = $max;
        $max = $diff;
        $thirdMaxName = $secondMaxName;
        $secondMaxName = $maxName;
        $maxName = $d['name'];
    }elseif($diff > $secondMax){
        $thirdMax = $secondMax;
        $secondMax = $diff;
        $thirdMaxName = $secondMaxName;
        $secondMaxName = $d['name'];
    }elseif($diff > $thirdMax){
        $thirdMax = $diff;
        $thirdMaxName = $d['name'];
    }
}

echo $maxName, " " , $secondMaxName," " ,$thirdMaxName;
```

[**Online Fiddle**](https://onecompiler.com/php/3ythnw7vg)

Comment: it give different results from the solution from other guys, need to check which solution actually working

Comment: @sikirajca You are free to test. Note that your sample input has 2 elements and you are looking for top 3 elements in the array. I hope that isn't confusing you.

Comment: your solution actually counts top 3 longest

Comment: can i change this code to return full element, not only the name?

Comment: @sikirajca Glad to hear that. Yes, instead of just getting the `name` key, you can directly assign the element.

Comment: @sikirajca See fiddle https://onecompiler.com/php/3ythstzhz

Answer (score 2):

I fully endorse the efficiency of @nice_dev's linear solution.  Here is an altered version which is easier to adjust -- only the `$size` variable needs to be adjusted for larger/smaller filtered sets instead of hardcoding so many individual variables.

The `unset()` calls are safe to make even when the targeted element doesn't exist and serve to ensure that the temporary and result arrays never grow beyond the declared limit.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bVd1H))

```
$size = 3;
$maxes = array_fill(0, $size, 0);
$names = [];

foreach ($array as $row) {
    $diff = strtotime($row['actual_end']) - strtotime($row['actual_start']);
    foreach ($maxes as $i => $max) {
        if ($diff > $max) {
             array_splice($maxes, $i, 0, $diff);
             array_splice($names, $i, 0, $row['name']);
             unset($maxes[$size], $names[$size]);
             break;
        }
    }
}

echo implode(' ', $names);
```

---

A direct, functional approach with slightly worse time complexity is to sort the entire array, then slice off the row data that you desire.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nk29X))

```
array_multisort(
    array_map(
        fn($row) => (new DateTime($row['actual_end']))->getTimestamp()
                    - (new DateTime($row['actual_start']))->getTimestamp(),
        $array
    ),
    SORT_DESC,
    $array
);
var_export(
    array_column(
        array_slice($array, 0, 3),
        'name'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a user defined function to tell [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) that you want your array sorted by the timespans, something like:

```php
$data = [
    [
        'name' => 'LILI',
        'actual_start' => '2021-11-10T18:34:00+00:00',
        'actual_end' => '2021-11-10T21:32:00+00:00',
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'MILI',
        'actual_start' => '2021-11-18T17:33:00+00:00',
        'actual_end' => '2022-03-18T19:36:00+00:00',
    ],

    // ... and more ...

];
    
usort($data, function($a, $b){

    $startA = new DateTime($a['actual_start']) ;
    $endA = new DateTime($a['actual_end']);
    $lengthA = $startA->diff( $endA );

    $startB = new DateTime($b['actual_start']) ;
    $endB = new DateTime($b['actual_end']);
    $lengthB = $startB->diff( $endB );

    // DateInterval objects can no longer be compared
    // compare the number of seconds instead
    return $lengthA->s <=> $lengthB->s;
});

$topThree = array_slice($data, 0, 3);
$bottomThree = array_slice($data, 0, -3);
```

Comment: what in your example represents $a and $b? because my array has >2000 elements not only 2 as in the inital example

Comment: Both $a and $b will be elements of your array. The sort function takes two and compares them in order to re-order your array. 2000 is a lot but should be doable. If coming from a database select might be worth sorting at that point though.

Comment: this solution doesn't calculate top 3

Comment: This approach [is very unsuitable](https://3v4l.org/fEtKn).  The `s` property of the `diff()` object has a max of `59`.  The results from this answer will be terribly unreliable.

Answer (score -2):

I'd probably sort the whole thing and grab the top three records for this.

Something like:

```
function span($record) {
  $start = new DateTime($record['actual_start']) ;
  $end = new DateTime($record['actual_end']);
  return $start->diff( $end );
}

function byDuration($a, $b) {
  $diffA = span($a);
  $diffB = span($b);
  if ($diffA == $diffB) return 0;
  return ($diffA < $diffB) ? -1 : 1;
}

$sorted = uasort($data, byDuration);
$top3 = array_slice($sorted, 0, 3);
```

disclaimer: typed in the SO textbook, haven't touched php since version 5.4 was the hot new thing.

Comment: There is too much in this clearly untested answer that readers should not be seeing.  Please test your code before posting.